# Use external code inside wolkenkit writeModels

Tags: wolkenkit

I am trying to use external code inside my writeModels. I tried to use a NPM package by requiring it (`const AXIOS = require('axios');`), but afterwards, wolkenkit fails to run/start (I think it times out after the ping). 
Is what I am trying to do even possible? I bet a lot of people would love to use NPM packages inside their writeModels (lodash, for example).

Comment: Did you add it to the project‘s package.json file?

Comment: Yes.
And it worked with node standard stuff like https, too. Just seems a bit weird - maybe the npm import mechanisms are breaking something?

Comment: The Node.js modules (such as `http`& co.) work out of the box, without further ado. You can basically use any (publicly available) npm module. We do use that in the [boards sample application](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-boards/blob/master/package.json#L46-L50), so there might be some other problem. Can you please add your `package.json` file to the question above?

Comment: I will throw together a gist once I have the time and add it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like I am unable to reproduce the error I encountered and it doesn't help that I threw away the changes in a hurry, because i wanted to finish the aggregate.

I can add the packages I want to use by adding them via `yarn add` or `npm install`, and I can use them by requiring them inside the file:

```
// server/writeModel/domain/aggregate.js
const AXIOS = require('axios');

const initialState = {

// rest of the file…
```

wolkenkit is working just fine, it must have been a mistake on my end.

Comment: Although it would have been interesting to figure out the original problem, I'm glad that things are working as expected (again) 